# Setters don't modify two-dimensional array

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Kotlin. I want a button to display values from a two-dimensional `ArrayList`, and a second button to modify one of them. But the setters don't modify the two-dimensional `ArrayList`. We can see the values with the first button, and after modifying the values at index 2 (third) with the second button, the values don't change:

```
 model.get(2).setDateStrs("03/03/20")
    model.get(2).setHourStrs("10:27")
```

What's wrong?

ReModel.kt file:

```
package com.example.updatearraylist
class ReModel {
    var dateStr:String = "12/31/2029"
    var hourStr: String = "00:00"
    fun getDateStrs(): String {
        return dateStr
    }
    fun setDateStrs(dateStr: String) {
        this.dateStr = dateStr
    }
    fun getHourStrs(): String {
        return hourStr
    }
    fun setHourStrs(hourStr: String) {
        this.hourStr = hourStr
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.example.updatearraylist
import android.R.attr
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.lang.reflect.Array.get
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var displayValueBtn: Button? = null
    private var changeValueBtn: Button? = null
    val model: ArrayList<ReModel>
        get() {
            val list = ArrayList<ReModel>()
            for (i in 0..7) {
                val model = ReModel()
                model.setDateStrs("01/16/2020")
                model.setHourStrs("01:08")
                list.add(model)
            }
            return list
        }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        displayValueBtn =findViewById<Button>(R.id.displayValueBtn)
        changeValueBtn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.changeValueBtn)

        displayValueBtn!!.setOnClickListener {
            for(i in 0..7){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Value position "+i+" "+model.get(i).getDateStrs()+" "+
                        model.get(i).getHourStrs()
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        changeValueBtn!!.setOnClickListener {
            model.get(2).setDateStrs("03/03/20")
            model.get(2).setHourStrs("10:27")
            Toast.makeText(this,"List Modified",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom getter on `model` will be executed each time `model` is accessed so any changes to the array are overwritten.  If you want to verify that use a single `println` in the custom getter and whatever you print will display multiple times.

By "custom getter" I mean the `get()` on `model` and the associated block of code.

One solution is to use lazy initialization instead of a custom getter so  that `model` is initialized only once.  Here's how that would look:

```
    val model: ArrayList<ReModel> by lazy {
            val list = ArrayList<ReModel>()
            for (i in 0..7) {
                val model = ReModel()
                model.setDateStrs("01/16/2020")
                model.setHourStrs("01:08")
                list.add(model)
            }
            list
        }
```

Note that the last line with just `list` on it returns the value of list.  `return` is not allowed there.

Comment: No problem @Elbio, glad to help.  BTW, welcome to stackoverflow!  If my answer solved the issue, marking it as the accepted answer and up voting it are two things that are considered good etiquette on stackoverflow.  I upvoted your question because I thought it provided all the information I needed to provide an answer. This upvote increased your reputation by 10 points.